# Error with using get on an API (Vue.js, express.js)

Tags: express, vue.js, sequelize.js

That's my first question on this website.

I have created my own API for a school project with few routes:

[The few routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQLpl.png)

```
app.get('/AREA/', (req, res) => res.status(200).send({
    message: 'Welcome to the AREA API'
}));

app.get('/AREA/Users', User.list);

app.post('/AREA/User', AuthPolicies.register, User.create);
app.get('/AREA/User', User.recup);
```

This is how I call the last get and post call:

Client:

[How I call in the component client part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF2jO.png)

```
    RecupUser: function () {
      this.error = ''
      const User = {
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      }
      AuthServices.login(User)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    }
```

[Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnyN8.png)

```
  register (credentials) {
    return Api.post('/AREA/User', credentials)
  },
  login (credentials) {
    return Api.get('/AREA/User', credentials)
  }
```

API:

[Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IHUf.png)

```
    create(req, res) {
        return User
         .create({
             'email': req.body.email,
             'password': req.body.password
         })
         .then(response => res.status(200).send(response))
         .catch(res.status(400).send({
            error: 'This email account is already in use.'
          }));
    },
    recup(req, res) {
        return User
         .findOne({where: {email: req.body.email},})
         .then(user => res.status(200).send({
             user: user.toJSON()
         }))
         .catch(err => res.status(400).send({
            error: err
          }));
    }
```

Error Recup:

```
Error: "Request failed with status code 400"
    createError createError.js:16
    settle settle.js:17
    handleLoad xhr.js:59
Login.vue:62
```

All work except the app.get('/AREA/User', User.recup) and I really want to try to find the reason why (I also tried with asyc await and had the same problem).

Does someone has an idea, I thought it was because it didn't pass by my route but i don't see why.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I assume you're seeing that error message in the browser? Are you seeing any error messages in the server logs/console? Also check the response body for the failing request in the Network tab of the developer tools.

Comment: Yes the Api is considering that my req.body is empty : {}
in recup(req, res) that's why i assumed he wasn't passing by the get(sorry for the terrible english. How do you mention someone ?) @skirtle

Comment: The exact Error that I have is `Error: WHERE parameter "email" has invalid "undefined" value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a GET request here:

```js
login (credentials) {
  return Api.get('/AREA/User', credentials)
}
```

A GET request cannot have a body.

If you want to pass a body you must use a POST request, or one of the other request types.

For a GET request the alternative to a body is to use query parameters. These are just appended to the end of the URL in the form `?param=value`. I don't know how `Api.get` is implemented so I can't give specific advice about how to pass query parameters to it.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, I didn't knew about this. the api is just an axio call to localhost